# Finding Diameter of a Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I have written code for finding the diameter of binary tree. But I am unable to figure out where is it going wrong . The two functions that I have written and their definition are as follows :-

```
    int btree::diameteroftree(node* leaf)
    { 
     if (leaf==NULL) 
     return 0;

     int lheight = hieghtoftree(leaf->left);
     int rheight = hieghtoftree(leaf->right);

     int ldiameter = diameteroftree(leaf->left);
     int rdiameter = diameteroftree(leaf->right);

     return max(lheight + rheight + 1,max(ldiameter,rdiameter));
   }


   int btree::hieghtoftree(node* leaf)
   {
    int left=0,right=0;
    if(leaf==NULL)
    return -1;
    else
    {
     left=hieghtoftree(leaf->left);
     right=hieghtoftree(leaf->right);
     if(left > right)
     return left +1;
     else
     return right+1;   
    }
   }
```

I am unable to figure out where am I going wrong here . Can someone let me know ...

Comment: What is the diameter of the tree? In what sense is a tree circular or spherical?

Comment: @paxdiablo: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html

Comment: I created a binary search tree with elements 41,31,28,23,21,37,35,40
32,36,60,55,52,67,58,63,69,33 . I am getting the output as 7 .

Comment: -1 for "Code dump: fix unknown bug plix". What have you actually tried?

Comment: @DeadMG I am not getting any core dump .. I just got the wrong answer

Comment: @DeadMG when are you getting core dump ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to return the number of nodes on the longest path. Therefore, the problem in your algorithm is this line:

```
return max(lheight + rheight + 1,max(ldiameter,rdiameter));
```

where

```
rootDiameter = lheight + rheight + 1
```

is the length of the path from the deepest node of the left tree to the deepest node of the right tree. However, this calculation is not correct. A single node returns a height of 0, so it will not be counted. You have two options:

1. Change `hieghtoftree` to return the number of nodes on the deepest path and not the number of "hops"
2. Address this problem in your summation

.

```
return max(lheight + rheight + 3,max(ldiameter,rdiameter));
```

Comment: This seems more apt. actually I used the genralised function for hieght of tree where I return -1 in case root is NULL and 0 in case tree has 1 element root.

Answer (score 0):

In a directed, rooted tree, there is always at most one path between any pair of nodes and the longest path to any node always starts at the root. It follows that the [diameter](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html) is simply the height of the entire tree `height(root)`, which can be computed with the recursion

```
height(leaf) = 0
height(node) = max(height(node.left), height(node.right)) + 1
```

**EDIT**: the page you link to in the comment describes the diameter of an *undirected* tree. You need a different tree representation, e.g. an adjacency matrix.

Comment: what in case root is NULL in that case hiegt returned will be 0 . Is it right ?

Comment: @Invictus: what else would it be?

Comment: 0 hieght represents that tree has a root . With Root having NULL value means tree does not exist .In this case a value other than 0 dhould be returned and that for my case is -1

Comment: @Invictus: that's nonstandard, but easily solved: set the root's height to -1 in the recursion or subtract one afterward.

Comment: root hieght is supposed to be 0 not -1 yeah I can always handle it outside but I didnot wanted a special case here

Answer (score 0):

Consider a 3-node tree with root R and 2 leaves L1, L2. Then heightoftree(L1) == heightoftree(L2) == -1. Diameteroftree(R) would therefore be (-1)+(-1)+1 = -1 ?!?

I suggest return -1; --> return 0;
and 
return max(lheight + rheight + 1,max(ldiameter,rdiameter)); --> return max(lheight + rheight + 2,max(ldiameter,rdiameter));

The result would be the number of edges on the path. If you count the number of nodes, then add one or subtract one from the final result according to your need.

Comment: Hiegt of L1= Hieght of L2 in that case will be 0 and that of their NUll child be -1 . and hence 0 will be returned to root and then the root returns 1 which is actually the hieght

Comment: @Invictus: What diameter do you want to be returned for this example tree? 2 or 3?

Comment: @Nico Schertler for the e.g I cited above in comment for my Tree I want it to be 9 , In your case its gonna be 3