# Diameter of Binary Tree Off by 1

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, tree, binary-tree

I am new to recursion and trees. I am having trouble figuring out the diameter of a binary tree. My solution is off by 1 and I can't figure out where I am going wrong. I have taken a look at a similar question here: [Finding Diameter of a Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446018/finding-diameter-of-a-tree) but I am not able to understand if it is indeed the same problem. The answer for the figure below has a diameter of 8 (longest path between two nodes). However I am getting 7. Any help or advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The questions can be found here: https://leetcode.com/explore/challenge/card/30-day-leetcoding-challenge/529/week-2/3293/

I am failing just 4 of the 106 test cases.

[image]

```
public class DiameterBinaryTree {

    public static void main(String argv[]){
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(1);
        root.left = new TreeNode(2);
        root.right = new TreeNode(3);
        System.out.println(diameter(root));
    }

    public static int diameter(TreeNode root){
        int maxDiameter = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        return diameterHelper(root, maxDiameter) ;
    }

    public static int diameterHelper(TreeNode root, int maxDiameter){
        if(root == null ) return 0;
        diameterHelper(root.left, maxDiameter);
        int leftHeight = findHeight(root.left);
        diameterHelper(root.right, maxDiameter);
        int rightHeight = findHeight(root.right);
        return Math.max(maxDiameter, leftHeight + rightHeight) ;
    }

    public static int findHeight(TreeNode root ){
        int countLeft = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int countRight = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        return findHeightHelper(root, countLeft, countRight) ;
    }

    public static int findHeightHelper(TreeNode root, int countLeft, int countRight){
        if(root == null ) return 0;
        countLeft = 1 + findHeightHelper(root.left, countLeft, countRight);
        countRight = 1 + findHeightHelper(root.right, countLeft, countRight);
        return Math.max(countLeft, countRight) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not consider the max diameter of he left and max diameter of the right before I compare the current diameter.

return  Math.max(Math.max(leftDiameter, rightDiameter), leftHeight + rightHeight);